# How do I make a year view on the KendoUI Scheduler?

Tags: model-view-controller, kendo-ui

I have started to use the KendoUI Scheduler in my MVC Project, I would like to add a year view to the scheduler which isn't available out of the box.  After searching around for ways to do this I found a lot of people talking about creating a custom view and overriding the date ranges of the scheduler.

The problem is that I'm not sure how to get this to work as a lot of the threads are old and links are broken.  There are a couple of examples out there but I've found them to be unclear and so I hope I can get some assistance here.

The first thing I have done is created my scheduler on my page using razor syntax.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Scheduler<Melina.ViewModels.TimelineVessels>()
    .Name("scheduler")
    .Date(new DateTime(2013, 6, 13))
    .StartTime(new DateTime(2013, 6, 13, 7, 00, 00))    
    .Views(views =>
    {
        views.TimelineView(timeline => timeline.EventHeight(50));            
        views.TimelineMonthView(timeline =>
        {
            timeline.StartTime(new DateTime(2013, 6, 13, 00, 00, 00));
            timeline.EndTime(new DateTime(2013, 6, 13, 00, 00, 00));                
        }).Selected(true);
        views.CustomView("YearView");
    })        
    .Group(group => group.Resources("Cars").Orientation(SchedulerGroupOrientation.Vertical))
    .Resources(resource =>
    {
        resource.Add(m => m.CarId)
            .Title("Car")
            .Name("Cars")
            .DataTextField("Title")
            .DataValueField("CarId")
            .DataSource(source =>
            {
                source.Read(read =>
                {
                    read.Action("ReadCars", "Report");
                });
            });
    })
    .DataSource(d => d
        .Model(m =>
        {
            m.Id(f => f.HireId);
            m.Field(f => f.Title).DefaultValue("No Title");
            m.Id(f => f.CarId);
            m.Field(f => f.Title).DefaultValue("No Title");
        })
        .Read("ReadHires", "Report")
    )
)
```

The scheduler shows a list of cars and then all their hire periods over the months, the problem with that is that some cars are on hire for months at a time and the scheduler shows very granular days and times.  To get around this I want to add this custom view, you can see this deinfed above as `YearView`.

Here is my javascript that handles this which is where I am struggling to get things working.

```
var YearView = kendo.ui.MultiDayView.extend({        
    nextDate: function () { return kendo.date.nextDay(this.startDate()); },
    options: { selectedDateFormat: "{0:D} - {1:D}" },
    name: "YearView",
    calculateDateRange: function () {
        var start = this.options.date,
            idx, length,
            dates = [];

        for (idx = 0, length = 12; idx < length; idx++) {
            dates.push(start);
            start = kendo.date.nextDay(start);
        }

        this._render(dates);
    }
});
```

This code was taken from a sample but it's a 3 day view, does anyone know how I could create my own year view either by adjust the above script or making a new one?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be to create a custom view by extending the "Timeline" view.

Then override the "calculateDateRange" method in order to show the full year.

Paraphrased a similar answer from [this](https://www.telerik.com/forums/timeline-year-view) forum post on Telerik website.